# Hide half of border with grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, opacity, mask

How hide half of brush with opacity mask with no path element? I want to make site "transparent".

```
    <Border Height="32" Width="32" x:Name="b1" CornerRadius="50" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red">

    </Border>
    <Grid Height="32" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="hideHaf" Background="Blue" >

    </Grid>
```

Default:

[image]

I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case your primary goal is to draw a vertical half transparent circle. You could do it this way instead of using the `Border`:

```
    <Path Width="16" Height="32" Stretch="Fill" Data="M5,0 A5,5,0,0,0,5,10" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: path is good way but it element is sometimes resize and i cant stop it

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail what problem you see with resizing? When you set `Stretch` to `Uniform` and leave out the `Height` and `Width` setting the path resizes properly.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply put your border insize the grid, and use the default `ClipToBounds="True"` property of the grid to clip the border like this:

```
    <Grid Height="32" Width="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right" x:Name="hideHaf">
        <Border Height="32" Width="32" x:Name="b1" CornerRadius="50" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red"/>
    </Grid>
```

Which produces:

[image]